# OpenVPN client suddenly refuses to connect to my self-hosted VPN

Tags: vpn, aws, openvpn

It's been working fine for years, but now suddenly I'm getting a strange error. Does anyone know what problem this points to?

OpenVPN Connect Version 3.0.2 (598), error logs:

```
[REDACTED IPs]

5/16/2021, 2:54:17 AM OpenVPN core 3.git::d8d14e19 mac x86_64 64-bit PT_PROXY built on Apr  5 2019 07:54:59
5/16/2021, 2:54:17 AM Frame=512/2048/512 mssfix-ctrl=1250
5/16/2021, 2:54:17 AM EVENT: RESOLVE ⏎5/16/2021, 2:54:17 AM UNUSED OPTIONS
4 [nobind] 
18 [sndbuf] [0] 
19 [rcvbuf] [0] 
22 [verb] [3] 
31 [CLI_PREF_ALLOW_WEB_IMPORT] [True] 
32 [CLI_PREF_BASIC_CLIENT] [False] 
33 [CLI_PREF_ENABLE_CONNECT] [True] 
34 [CLI_PREF_ENABLE_XD_PROXY] [True] 
35 [WSHOST] [35.158.212.188:443] 
36 [WEB_CA_BUNDLE] [-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE----- MIIDBj[REDACTED]BgkqhkiG...] 
37 [IS_OPENVPN_WEB_CA] [1] 
38 [ORGANIZATION] [OpenVPN Inc] 
⏎5/16/2021, 2:54:17 AM Contacting [REDACTED]:1194 via UDP
⏎5/16/2021, 2:54:17 AM EVENT: WAIT ⏎5/16/2021, 2:54:17 AM Connecting to [REDACTED]:1194 ([REDACTED]) via UDPv4
⏎5/16/2021, 2:54:17 AM Tunnel Options:V4,dev-type tun,link-mtu 1558,tun-mtu 1500,proto UDPv4,comp-lzo,keydir 1,cipher AES-256-CBC,auth SHA1,keysize 256,tls-auth,key-method 2,tls-client
⏎5/16/2021, 2:54:17 AM Creds: Username/Password
⏎5/16/2021, 2:54:17 AM Peer Info:
IV_VER=3.git::d8d14e19
IV_PLAT=mac
IV_NCP=2
IV_TCPNL=1
IV_PROTO=2
IV_LZO_STUB=1
IV_COMP_STUB=1
IV_COMP_STUBv2=1
IV_HWADDR=f4:5c:89:cd:69:cd

⏎5/16/2021, 2:54:17 AM EVENT: CONNECTING ⏎5/16/2021, 2:54:17 AM SSL Handshake: TLSv1.2/TLS-ECDHE-RSA-WITH-AES-256-GCM-SHA384
⏎5/16/2021, 2:54:17 AM EVENT: GET_CONFIG ⏎5/16/2021, 2:54:17 AM Session is ACTIVE
⏎5/16/2021, 2:54:17 AM Sending PUSH_REQUEST to server...
⏎5/16/2021, 2:54:17 AM OPTIONS:
0 [explicit-exit-notify] 
1 [topology] [subnet] 
2 [route-delay] [5] [30] 
3 [dhcp-pre-release] 
4 [dhcp-renew] 
5 [dhcp-release] 
6 [route-metric] [101] 
7 [ping] [12] 
8 [ping-restart] [50] 
9 [compress] [stub-v2] 
10 [redirect-gateway] [def1] 
11 [redirect-gateway] [bypass-dhcp] 
12 [redirect-gateway] [autolocal] 
13 [route-gateway] [172.27.232.1] 
14 [dhcp-option] [DNS] [172.31.0.2] 
15 [register-dns] 
16 [block-ipv6] 
17 [ifconfig] [172.27.232.5] [255.255.248.0] 
18 [peer-id] [1] 
19 [auth-token] ...
20 [cipher] [AES-256-GCM] 

⏎5/16/2021, 2:54:17 AM Session token: [redacted]
⏎5/16/2021, 2:54:17 AM Server has pushed compressor COMP_STUBv2, but client has disabled compression, switching to asymmetric
⏎5/16/2021, 2:54:17 AM PROTOCOL OPTIONS:
  cipher: AES-256-GCM
  digest: SHA1
  compress: COMP_STUBv2
  peer ID: 1
⏎5/16/2021, 2:54:17 AM TunPersist: long-term session scope
⏎5/16/2021, 2:54:17 AM TunPersist: new tun context
⏎5/16/2021, 2:54:17 AM CAPTURED OPTIONS:
Session Name: 35.158.212.188
Layer: OSI_LAYER_3
MTU: 1500
Remote Address: [REDACTED]
Tunnel Addresses:
  172.27.232.5/21 -> 172.27.232.1
Reroute Gateway: IPv4=1 IPv6=0 flags=[ ENABLE REROUTE_GW AUTO_LOCAL DEF1 BYPASS_DHCP IPv4 ]
Block IPv6: yes
Route Metric Default: 101
Add Routes:
Exclude Routes:
DNS Servers:
  172.31.0.2
Search Domains:

⏎5/16/2021, 2:54:17 AM SetupClient: transmitting tun setup list to /var/run/ovpnagent.sock
{
    "config" : 
    {
        "iface_name" : "",
        "layer" : "OSI_LAYER_3",
        "tun_prefix" : false
    },
    "tun" : 
    {
        "adapter_domain_suffix" : "",
        "block_ipv6" : true,
        "dns_servers" : 
        [
            {
                "address" : "172.31.0.2",
                "ipv6" : false
            }
        ],
        "layer" : 3,
        "mtu" : 1500,
        "remote_address" : 
        {
            "address" : "[REDACTED]",
            "ipv6" : false
        },
        "reroute_gw" : 
        {
            "flags" : 315,
            "ipv4" : true,
            "ipv6" : false
        },
        "route_metric_default" : 101,
        "session_name" : "[REDACTED]",
        "tunnel_address_index_ipv4" : 0,
        "tunnel_address_index_ipv6" : -1,
        "tunnel_addresses" : 
        [
            {
                "address" : "172.27.232.5",
                "gateway" : "172.27.232.1",
                "ipv6" : false,
                "metric" : -1,
                "net30" : false,
                "prefix_length" : 21
            }
        ]
    }
}
POST unix://[/var/run/ovpnagent.sock]/tun-setup : E_CONNECT HTTPCore Asio handle_unix_connect: No such file or directory
⏎5/16/2021, 2:54:17 AM TUN Error: ovpnagent: communication error
⏎5/16/2021, 2:54:17 AM Client exception in transport_recv: tun_exception: not connected
⏎5/16/2021, 2:54:17 AM EVENT: ASSIGN_IP ⏎5/16/2021, 2:54:17 AM EVENT: TUN_SETUP_FAILED ovpnagent: communication error⏎5/16/2021, 2:54:17 AM EVENT: DISCONNECTED ⏎5/16/2021, 2:54:19 AM Raw stats on disconnect:
  BYTES_IN : 3120
  BYTES_OUT : 2182
  PACKETS_IN : 8
  PACKETS_OUT : 7
  TUN_SETUP_FAILED : 1
⏎5/16/2021, 2:54:19 AM Performance stats on disconnect:
  CPU usage (microseconds): 10806780
  Network bytes per CPU second: 490
  Tunnel bytes per CPU second: 0
⏎
```

Comment: I don't see a security question here. Looks like you are just trying to troubleshoot some client/server software.

Comment: I don't see this question really on-topic. It is probably better asked at the dedicated support forums for this software, i.e. https://forums.openvpn.net/

Comment: I searched Stackexchange for the correct sub, and found many OpenVPN questions posted to security.stackexchange.com. If you have a suggestion for a better Stackexchange, please let me know. As for "just trying to troubleshoot", what else are we doing on Stackexchange?!

Comment: @knutole: *"...  what else are we doing on Stackexchange"* - if you would take a closer look at [security.se], then you might realize that the majority of question are about understanding how things work (i.e. concepts) and not about troubleshooting specific problems. This is different from stackoverflow.com or superuser.com. So if you insist on using some generic SO site instead of asking at forums specific to OpenVPN, then superuser.com might be the better choice for troubleshooting.

Comment: Well, I stand corrected. I guess this Q doesn't belong here. Could you migrate it to Superuser by any chance, @SteffenUllrich?

Comment: @knutole: I can not migrate it myself. Anyway, I still think that https://forums.openvpn.net/ might be a better place to ask since it is specifically focused on OpenVPN problems.

Comment: I have same issue if this helps.  Looking for solution.